# Why does accessing pointer array using [] operator after increment the current memory position of return bad address?

Tags: c++

I know there is side effect of using the pointer arithmetic, but I could not figure out what is happening behind this

```
int * pointer_arr = new int [ 3 ] { 10, 11, 12 };

std::cout << * pointer_arr ++ << std::endl; // output 10 then increment
std::cout << ++ * pointer_arr << std::endl; // access then increment => output 12

++ * pointer_arr;

std::cout << pointer_arr [ 0 ] << std::endl; // should output 13
std::cout << pointer_arr [ 1 ] << std::endl; // should output 11
std::cout << pointer_arr [ 2 ] << std::endl; // should output 12, but this output 0 instead

delete [] pointer_arr;

// output
// also, it miss another element of 11
10
12
13
13
12
0
```

also if I try wrap the first one with parenthesis

```
std::cout << ( * pointer_arr ) ++ << std::endl;
```

the output will be

```
10
12
13
13
11
12
```

which is what I expected the above will print out. Then If i add another line which shift to second index below after the line which outputting 12,

```
std::cout << * ++ pointer_arr << std::endl;
```

this happens

```
10
12
11
12
12
12
-1342177820
```

I am trying to understand basic of pointer and I know there is side effect of doing arithmetic operation on pointer, but this confuses me. Please help me explain why outputting the last index of the array using [] operator after some certain operation or pointer arithmetic above would cause the unexpected result and differences between having parenthesis wrap around the pointer and no parenthesis wrap around.

Comment: I am suspecting sure this is a problem with operator precedence. Try the debugger or just change the values in your array to values farther apart (10,20,30 for example). My initial suspicion here is that when you think you're incrementing the value you're incrementing the pointer or vice versa but don't notice since they're only one apart anyway. This then causes out-of-bounds errors on the final value.

That's also why I recommend using parentheses for readability on non-trivial chained operators, since chained operators can get confusing if one mixes up precedence rules.

Comment: The best way to understand pointers is to bring out a pencil and a bunch of paper and start drawing boxes and arrows.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `* pointer_arr ++` will increase the *pointer*, not the element it points to. That means it will no longer point to the first element in the array but the second. That also means `pointer_arr[2]` will be *out of bounds* as it is the *fourth* element of your three-element array.

And then you pass that modified pointer to `delete[]`. You *must* pass the original pointer to `delete[]`.

Both the dereference and the `delete[]` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) where the postfix `++` operator have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. That means `* pointer_arr ++` is actually `* (pointer_arr ++)`

Comment: The * pointer_arr ++ will increment the element that it points to regardless of the precedence. Because the expression evaluate from inside to left and back to the right. In the first output, it first access the data, and pass to the << operator, then the ++ is the side effect, which increment the pointer but not the element it is pointing to correct ?

Comment: @lambda No, `*pointer_arr++` will increase *the pointer!* Try to print the pointer before and after and you will see. So will `*++pointer_arr`. But `++*pointer_arr` will increase what the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Yes, I did print out the pointer before and after. for *pointer_arr++, it will print out 10 first, and print it with * pointer_arr again will give me 11, which it already shift to the next location.
[ https://repl.it/repls/BoringGratefulWhitetaileddeer ]

Comment: @lambda No you're printing what it *points* to, not the actual pointer itself. Try changing the contents of the array (so it's not consecutive numbers) and try again. Also, print plain `pointers_arr` (without derefeencing) to get the raw pointer value.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want me to print out raw memory and check whether pointer_arr ++, will output the current pointer address then increment right ? In this case, it will print out the address of first index of the pointer_arr then increment after, if I print out only pointer_arr after, it will print out the address of the second elemennt in the array. 
[ https://repl.it/repls/MaleCornsilkNijssenissdwarfchihlid ]

Comment: If `pointers_arr` points to the second element in the array after the increment, then clearly the increment didn't increment the *value* now did it? It must have incremented the *pointer*, which I have been saying the whole time.

Comment: So * pointer_arr ++ in the end of the day, it will increment the pointer and shift to second index, so why does ( * pointer ) ++ will work as I first expected, which access the value and increment it while * pointer_arr ++ will instead increment on the pointer ? what is happening behind it and why does ( * pointer_arr ) ++ and * pointer_arr ++ output the same result, but the first one increment on the value that pointer pointed to and the second one increment on the pointer?

Comment: It's all a matter of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The associativity doesn't play any part in this.

Comment: Cold you please also take a look at this also [link] (https://repl.it/repls/OffbeatPopularSambar) ? Without create an array by allocating memory on the heap, the result is as my expected, but why does the code in this issue and compare with the link i just sent result differently ? The operator precedence somehow did not work in this I think and it is more like order of evaluation

Comment: also from this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/293291-use-of-prefix-and-postfix-operators-on-pointers/).  `*p++ = 1`, the *p will evaluate first then assign to 1 then increment the pointer to next index